# I Want to merge 2 Data Frames by a fraction of row Names

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have the following Data Tables and I want to merge them.
Problem: They have just not completely similar row names.

For Example

1. Data Frame row Names

Call.Dec.2018-Ask Price

Call.Dec.2017-Ask Price

Call.Dec.2015-Ask Price

Call.Dec.2013-Ask Price

Call.Dec.2019-Ask Price

Call.Dec.2029-Ask Price

2. Data Frame row names

Call.Dec.2018-Strike Price

Call.Dec.2017-Strike Price

Call.Dec.2015-Strike Price

Call.Dec.2013-Strike Price

Call.Dec.2019-Strike Price

Call.Dec.2029-Strike Price

I know that there is a solution but I can't find it.

Thanks for helping

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. What have you tried so far. Please paste the dataframes into the questions using the output of `dput(dataframe1)` and `dput(dataframe2)`. If you have moment check out [MRE] for guidance on asking questions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the column into two and then join:

```r
library(tidyverse)

tbl_a <- tibble::tribble(
  ~name,
   "Call.Dec.2017-Ask Price",
   "Call.Dec.2015-Ask Price",
   "Call.Dec.2013-Ask Price",
   "Call.Dec.2019-Ask Price",
   "Call.Dec.2029-Ask Price"
  ) %>%
  mutate(price = 1)
tbl_a
#> # A tibble: 5 × 2
#>   name                    price
#>   <chr>                   <dbl>
#> 1 Call.Dec.2017-Ask Price     1
#> 2 Call.Dec.2015-Ask Price     1
#> 3 Call.Dec.2013-Ask Price     1
#> 4 Call.Dec.2019-Ask Price     1
#> 5 Call.Dec.2029-Ask Price     1

tbl_b <- tibble::tribble(
  ~name,
   "Call.Dec.2017-Strike Price",
   "Call.Dec.2015-Strike Price",
   "Call.Dec.2013-Strike Price",
   "Call.Dec.2019-Strike Price",
   "Call.Dec.2029-Strike Price"
  ) %>%
  mutate(price = 2)
tbl_b
#> # A tibble: 5 × 2
#>   name                       price
#>   <chr>                      <dbl>
#> 1 Call.Dec.2017-Strike Price     2
#> 2 Call.Dec.2015-Strike Price     2
#> 3 Call.Dec.2013-Strike Price     2
#> 4 Call.Dec.2019-Strike Price     2
#> 5 Call.Dec.2029-Strike Price     2

list(tbl_a, tbl_b) %>%
  map(~ .x %>% separate(name, into = c("name", "type"), sep = "-")) %>%
  reduce(full_join) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = type, values_from = price)
#> Joining, by = c("name", "type", "price")
#> # A tibble: 5 × 3
#>   name          `Ask Price` `Strike Price`
#>   <chr>               <dbl>          <dbl>
#> 1 Call.Dec.2017           1              2
#> 2 Call.Dec.2015           1              2
#> 3 Call.Dec.2013           1              2
#> 4 Call.Dec.2019           1              2
#> 5 Call.Dec.2029           1              2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>